# New light switch has blue, black, and white wires. Wall has black, white, and ground. Can I make it work?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, wire

I bought a new light switch that is supposed to allow me to automate my lights easier. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

It has blue, black, and white wires. Coming out of my wall, however, I only have a white, black, and ground. The instructions say that I need two white wires or else the switch won't work:

[image]

Do I need to have a major rewire operation done to get this light to work? Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but for cases where you have no neutral in the switch (many older installs; NEC 2011 now requires neutral at switches), there are many switches/timers/etc sold as "No neutral required". If you are faced with rewiring, simply using a different switch may be a much cheaper/easier option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to run a grounded (neutral) conductor into the box. It sounds like the power is supplied to the fixture, and only a switch loop is run to the switch. You'll have to run a 3 conductor cable with ground (14/3 or 12/3), from the fixture to the switch.  If there is conduit between the fixture box and the switch box, you can simply pull an additional conductor.